# How to execute sqlite statements based of user response on select form with php?

Tags: php, html, sqlite

I've tried using the $_POST to get the result of the form and execute the SQLite select statement but an error shows up saying "Notice: Object of class SQLite3 could not be converted to int". Would a $_GET method be better? I'm still quite new to PHP and SQLite so any help would be welcomed.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="formSelect">
    <div id="chosen">
    <label for="pkCountry" class="blue">Choose a country:</label>
    <select name="selectBox" id="choose" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="start">select...</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
        <option value="England">England</option>
        <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
        <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
        <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="West Indies">West Indies</option>
    </select>
    <?php
    $db = new SQLite3('cricket.db');

    if (!$db) {
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } 
    else {
        if(isset($_POST['selectBox'])) {
            $nation = $_POST['selectBox'];

            $command = "SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country= $nation;";

            $db-exec($command);
            $db->close();
        }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `$db-exec($command);` - you forgot a `>` after `-` and now it's interpreting it as a minus, instead of member access to try and call the method.

Comment: You should also look into using prepared statements to avoid injection and quoting issues.

Answer (score 0):

first of all yo need put single quote ( ' ) before and after $nation like :

```
$command = "SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country='$nation';";
```

and i think its better  write like that :

```
function clearData($data){$data = strip_tags($data);$data = sqlite_escape_string($data);return $data;}


$command = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM batsman WHERE country='" . clearData($_POST['selectBox']) ."';");
$result = $command->execute();
$final_res = $result->fetchArray();
```

and you will has result as array